# How to 3d plot in matlab with points given, and join them?

Tags: matlab, plot

I've got few points and I wanted to draw them, and join them with line, I tried:

```
plot3(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
```

and so on up to about 100, but Im just getting plot with many points, how to join them with line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing right now is telling MATLAB to plot each point separately. What you should do is to store all your points as a vector and then use `plot3`. E.g.,

```
x=[x1,x2,...,xn];
y=[y1,y2,...,yn];
z=[z1,z2,...,zn];

plot3(x,y,z)
```

This way you get a line joining your points.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility which is using the low level function called `line`. By taking the above example, your code would look like this:

```
x=[x1,x2,...,xn];
y=[y1,y2,...,yn];
z=[z1,z2,...,zn];

line(x,y,z);
```